# Multi-Threading Can't Drawing Figures in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, jpanel, runnable

I want to create 2 threads.
One thread with moving rectangle, and another thread with second rectangle following first one. 
Here are pictures what i would like to achive.
[image]
[image]

How can i add my class "MovingRectangle" to a thread?
Or can i draw a figure (like rectangle) wchich can moving in a thread?
I found that in public void run() in Runnable i can't drawing here (Maybe iam wrong_)...
Sorry for that question, i have started Java few days ago and i can't find the answer for this.
Here is main:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main extends JFrame
{
            public Main()
            { }

        public static void main (String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

            JFrame f = new JFrame();

            New_Thread x = new New_Thread();
            f.add(x);
            f.setTitle("Window");
            f.setVisible(true);
            f.setSize(800,800);
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            Thread t1 = new Thread (new New_Thread());
            t1.start();
            Thread t2 = new Thread (new New_Thread());
            t2.start();

        }
}
```

Here is code for moving this rectangle:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

public class MovingRectangle extends square implements ActionListener {

    Timer t = new Timer (50,this);
    double x = 50;
    double y= 700;
    double velX= 10;
    double velY=10;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(Color.gray);
        Rectangle2D rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(x,y,40,40);
        g2.fill(rectangle);
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

       y = y - velY;
       if (y==90)
       {
           velY=0;
           x=x+velX;
       }

       if (x==600)
       {
           velY=10;
           velY=-velY;
       }

       if (x==600 && y == 700)
       {
           velY=0;
       }

        repaint();
    }


}
```

Here for little squares:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

public class square extends JPanel
{

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(Color.PINK);
        Rectangle2D towar1 = new Rectangle2D.Double(20,500,30,30);
        Rectangle2D towar2 = new Rectangle2D.Double(20,300,30,30);
        Rectangle2D towar3 = new Rectangle2D.Double(20,100,30,30);
        Rectangle2D towar4 = new Rectangle2D.Double(150,60,30,30);
        Rectangle2D towar5 = new Rectangle2D.Double(350,60,30,30);
        Rectangle2D towar6 = new Rectangle2D.Double(550,60,30,30);
        Rectangle2D towar7 = new Rectangle2D.Double(640,500,30,30);
        Rectangle2D towar8 = new Rectangle2D.Double(640,300,30,30);
        Rectangle2D towar9 = new Rectangle2D.Double(640,100,30,30);
        g2.fill(towar1);
        g2.fill(towar2);
        g2.fill(towar3);
        g2.fill(towar4);
        g2.fill(towar5);
        g2.fill(towar6);
        g2.fill(towar7);
        g2.fill(towar8);
        g2.fill(towar9);
    }
}
```

And here new thread wchich i would like to add MovingRectangle class (or just want to add code to move figure) but i have no idea how to  do that.

```
public class New_Thread extends MovingRectangle implements Runnable {
    @Override

    public void run()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Graphics stuff is usually single threaded, so all in all this is not a very good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found that in public void run() in Runnable i can't drawing here.

You are not wrong.  Most of the methods in `java.awt` and `javax.swing` may only be called from within the *[event dispatch thread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread)*.  That is to say, they may only be called from within an event handler of one kind or another.

Probably the best way to animate your two rectangles is to set up a *[Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)* that fires at regular intervals (e.g., 30x per second or 60x per second), and do your drawing from within the handler method that is called by the timer object.